# Nested Rules in SLD and/or nested filters

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am trying to create a SLD for symbology in a map. The map contains 9 counties with cultural assets by category and type. Current symbology is based on type. I would like to duplicate the map for each county and only show the assets in that county while still using the primary dataset filtered by the county field:
ogc:PropertyNamecounty</ogc:PropertyName>
ogc:LiteralArcher</ogc:Literal>.

```
    <sld:Rule>
      <sld:Title>Monuments</sld:Title>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>Monuments</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <sld:MinScaleDenominator>105.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
      <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>108335.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
      <sld:PointSymbolizer>
        <sld:Graphic>
          <sld:Mark>
            <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#2d8bc2</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
            <sld:Stroke>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#FFFFFF</sld:CssParameter>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Stroke>
          </sld:Mark>
          <sld:Size>14</sld:Size>
        </sld:Graphic>
      </sld:PointSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
```

At a loss as to where to insert the county filter. Can you create a county rule and nest all the symbology within based on type, or have to insert >type< and >county< for each.

Tried searching for nested rules and nested filters.

Answer (score 1):

Rule and filter nesting is not possible in SLD.
If you're looking into writing more compact styles, and your target is GeoServer, then have a look at GeoCSS instead, among other things, it supports free rule nesting:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/tutorial.html#applying-rule-nesting

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new layer for each county by adding a CQL filter in the box labelled `Restrict the features on layer by CQL filter` at the very bottom of the layer creation page. Then you could apply the same SLD to each layer.